# How do I get the CORS error which appears on the console, using Angular error handling?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-httpclient

I've put together my own little error handler to deal with HttpErrorResponses on the REST server, but I notice that things are going wrong on the client and Angular is wrapping them up as part of an HttpErrorResponse which gets passed to my error handler.

So in the console, first I see this:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/group' from origin
>   'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of
>   the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be
>   the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The
>   credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is
>   controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

which is to be expected under the circumstances, but I would like my error handler to log that error, only I can't see how. This is the handler as it's used:

```
 getGroups(): Observable<Group[]> {
    return this.http.get<Group[]>(`${this.restUrl}/group`).pipe(
        catchError(
            error => this.errorService.handleError<Group[]>(
                                    error, 'getGroups', [])
          )
      );
  }
```

and my error service:

```
  handleError<T>(
      error: HttpErrorResponse,
      operation = 'operation',
      result?: T) {
    this.messageService.add(`${operation} failed`);
    this.messageService.add(`HTTP error response: status[${error.status}];
                error.message:"${error.message}"`);
    this.messageService.add(`Is ErrorEvent? 
                ${error.error instanceof ErrorEvent ? "yes":"no"}`);
    this.messageService.add(`Is ProgressEvent? 
                ${error.error instanceof ProgressEvent ? "yes":"no"}`);

    return of(result as T);
  }
```

So Angular HttpClient has hopefully just wrapped that error - or completely replaced it. Can I get it in my error handler?

The output of my error handler is:

```
getGroups failed
HTTP error response: status[0]; error.message:"Http failure response for http://localhost:8080/group: 0 Unknown Error"
Is ErrorEvent? no
Is ProgressEvent? yes
```

And I can't see what I can do with `ProgressEvent`.

**[2019-02-28] Update**

As Anjil says in the comments, this CORS error is not an HTTP error. It is thrown somewhere by something - and I don't know what. Might be the browsers, might be Angular, RxJS, HttpClient.

Comment: I believe the CORS issue (message) is thrown by the browser not by the HttpClient if that's what you were trying to see in your error handler function.

Comment: By the browser - yes, I see. That makes complete sense - but then HttpClient gets the error surely? Maybe it doesn't get any message in the error it's given. I haven't tried Sabbir's solution yet, but hopefully it will show up.

Comment: I don't think it does. It throws an unknown url error or something along those lines. I've had my share of CORS issues in the past when I didn't know what CORS issue actually meant. :D

Answer (score 1):

You can try the code like below

```
getGroups(): Observable<Group[]> {
return this.http.get<Group[]>(`${this.restUrl}/group`).subscribe(
    results => {
      console.log(results)
    },
    err => {
      // Do stuff whith your error
      this.displayError(err);
    },
    () => {
      // Do stuff after completion
    }
  )
}

private displayError(ex): void {
    console.log(ex);
}
```

Comment: OK nice try but your `err` doesn't show anything different from my `error`